What happens to the person's Soul if he gets buried after death instead of cremation?
"According to Hindu custom, the deceased are cremated as it is believed that souls, after living in the body for long time, gets attached to the body and doesn't want to leave. Thus, if the body is not cremated and buried, the soul will linger in the vicinity and not depart."
This is a very common belief in Hinduism, so I believe i don't need to put up a reference from scriptures.
However the question i want to ask is, what if for example a person who doesn't have any relatives who'd cremate their body after death, what will happen to that person's Soul?
Normally if a person dies in India I'll assume the body would be found and burned by the authorities. But let's say the person is in a far away Foreign nation let's assume America and dies there and usually they bury the dead there, unless a will is written in advance by the person in this case we'll assume the person didn't wrote a will, and their body gets buried after death in a graveyard.

Just FYI, few hindu communities in southern India, they bury instead of cremation.

This has been settled by Krishna in the Bhagavad Gita
https://shlokam.org/bhagavad-gita/2-27/

जातस्य हि ध्रुवो मृत्युर्ध्रुवं जन्म मृतस्य च ।
तस्मादपरिहार्येऽर्थे न त्वं शोचितुमर्हसि ॥ २-२७॥


jātasya hi dhruvo mṛtyurdhruvaṃ janma mṛtasya ca
tasmādaparihārye’rthe na tvaṃ śocitumarhasi 2-27


Indeed, certain is death for the born, and certain is birth for the dead; therefore, over the inevitable, you should not grieve.

Krishna says nothing about the final rites given to the dead.
